# ReferenceError:data is not defined in at exports.action

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

I'm writing an action from an API.AI intent which parses the request and extracts the origin and the destination from the request.
The problem is it's throwing a Reference error and showing that the data is undefined.

```
ReferenceError: orginalData is not defined
at exports.distanceCalculator.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:16:43)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:652:7
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:636:9
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

index.js

```
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';
const App = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiApp;
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.distanceCalculator=functions.https.onRequest((request,response) =>{
  const app = new App({request, response});
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  var reJson,distance,duration,resText,reSon;
  var request=require('request');
  var orginalData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request.body || null);
  console.log("The data received is: "+originalData);
  var origin=orginalData.result.parameters.geo_city;
  var destination=orginalData.result.parameters.geo_city;
  var travelMode='driving';
  var reqURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+origin+"&destinations="+destination+"&mode="+travelMode;

  //Logger
  console.log('Origin: '+origin);
  console.log('Destination: '+destination);
  console.log('Travel Mode: '+travelMode);
  console.log('Request Url: '+reqURL);

  function disCal(app){
    //Google Maps API call
  request(reqURL,function(error,response,body){
    reJson=JSON.parse(body);
    distance=reJson.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
    duration=reJson.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
    resText="The distance between "+origin+" and "+destination+" is "+distance+" and it would take you "+duration+" to reach there"
  });

  console.log(global.resText);

     global.reSon=JSON.parse('{"displayText": global.resText}');
    app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => 
      {
        var reSon=JSON.parse('{"displayText": global.resText}');
        return res.json(reSon);
        });
    app.tell(reSon);
    return res.json(reSon);
  }
  let actionMap=new Map();
  actionMap.set('cities.distance',disCal);
  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you everything - what's wrong and the exact line.

Note that:

```
orginalData !== originalData
```

A good linter like ESLint would help you avoid mistakes like that. See:

- http://eslint.org/

Following a good style guide would also help you a lot. For example:

- http://airbnb.io/javascript/